# Information about NADADEM files .inc and .inc0 files

Tags: digital-image-processing, nasadem

By NASADEM, it is available to download DEM data for worldwide, they sort theirs data into subdirectories `hgt_merge, hgt_srtmOnly, inc, inc0` etc.

I am interested in the directory `inc` and `inc0`, they contain the tiles as files with `.inc` extension and `.inc0` respectively.

following the documentation:
`.inc` files are:

> "Subswath radar incidence angle (relative to ellipsoid)"

and `.inc` files are:

> "Subswath radar incidence angle (local)"

I know already what these angles are, but my question is, what are the shorcuts and the numbers by naming such files `081_080_ss1_d_1_1` etc.
Each tile has 11 own files, for example the tile `N52E009` has:

```
n52e009_081_080_ss1_d_1_1.inc
n52e009_081_080_ss2_d_1_1.inc
n52e009_097_080_ss2_d_1_1.inc
n52e009_097_080_ss3_d_1_1.inc
n52e009_097_080_ss4_d_1_1.inc
n52e009_122_280_ss4_a_1_1.inc
n52e009_138_280_ss1_a_1_1.inc
n52e009_138_280_ss2_a_1_1.inc
n52e009_138_280_ss3_a_1_1.inc
n52e009_138_280_ss4_a_1_1.inc
n52e009_154_280_ss1_a_1_1.inc
```